# Black ops 2 Prestige Gun and prestige level

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

If I Prestige in Black Ops 2, will my gun levels and camos get reset as well?
For example, my PDW is Prestige two with gold camo.

Answer (score 4):

If you Prestige in Black Ops 2 your guns will be re-locked just as if you had just started playing the game. Once you reach the level it takes to unlock that particular gun you can unlock it. You still have your gun prestige, camo's, and attachments. You also get a reward for prestiging which can be either getting all of your unlock tokens back or getting another create-a-class. You will also get one permanent unlock coin when you prestige. So therefore you can keep your favorite gun unlocked. You get the rewards every time you prestige.

Comment: I'll add that you also keep your challenges.